# How do I improve SQL Server query performance when doing a LIKE over many columns

Tags: sql-server, performance, full-text-search

My query needs to do a LIKE search over 3 columns.

```
SELECT * FROM Monkeys
WHERE [Name] LIKE '%pete%' OR [Desc] LIKE '%pete%' OR [Info] LIKE '%pete%';
```

I am looking to improve the performance of this query.

I can't use full-text catalogs, just simple tables. There are about 200,000 rows (SQL Server 2008 database) and it takes 3 to 6 seconds.

Doe anyone have any tips?

Comment: You cannot get good performance when using a wildcard as the first character as indexes cannot be used. This indicates a poor design you should not need to do this type of search, nor should the data possibly be in one of three columns.

Comment: If you use a search term `LIKE %pete%` you're tossing out all chances of ever using an index. You really won't be able to speed up such a query - short of giving up the %pete% search term and using something else to search (or using fulltext searching)

Answer (score 4):

Full text indexing/search if you have leading wildcards.

No amount of normal indexing will help you to make it fast, sorry, whether multiple or single columns with wildcards.

Your <strike>best</strike> least worst chance is to have composite index on the 3 columns and hope the optimizer scans this rather a table scan, but frankly I've not tried it myself. And likely you can't because index key column combined width has to be less than 900 bytes